# HTTP OPTIONS request to java server

Tags: java

I have a server class and a client class in java.

The fact is that I am testing on localhost and I want my server to answer the request OPTIONS of HTTP.

I do not know what I am doing wrong, my client server receives the request but does not return what I want and I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

I leave here both the client class and the server to see if someone throws some light at this problem.

CLIENT TCP

```
public class clientetcp {

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {

        /*
         * Leemos los argumentos del programa para saber a qué
         * servidor hay que conectarse.
         */
        if (argv.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("java clientetcp servidor");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        Socket socket = null;
        InetAddress address;
        byte[] mensaje_bytes = new byte[256];
        String mensaje = "";

        try {
            /*
             * Establecemos una conexión con el servidor en el puerto 6001 y 
             * enviamos lo que el usuario escribe por teclado. Acabamos con la
             * palabra end.
             */

            address = InetAddress.getByName(argv[0]);
            socket = new Socket(address, 6001);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            do {

                 out.writeUTF("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0");
                 out.writeUTF("");   // blank line separating header & body
                 out.flush();

                 String line;
                 line = in.readUTF();
                 System.out.println(line);
            } while (!mensaje.startsWith("end"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {

            if (socket != null) {
                System.out.println("Cerrando socket cliente ...");
                socket.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

SERVER TCP

```
public class servidortcp {

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        String mensaje;
        PrintWriter salida = null;
        String salidaOstias;
        String pedro;

        try {

            /*
             * Creamos un socket de tipo servidor que escucha en el puerto
             * TCP 6001 y espera conexiones de los clientes.
             * Este programa recibe lo que viene del socket y lo muestra
             * por pantalla.
             */
            socket = new ServerSocket(6001);
            Socket socket_cli = socket.accept();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket_cli.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket_cli.getOutputStream());
            do {
                mensaje = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println(mensaje);
                out.writeUTF("CONTESTO A LO QUE ME HAS DICHO");

            } while (1 > 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (socket != null) {
                System.out.println("Cerrando socket servidor ...");
                socket.close();
            }
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP makes no use whatsoever of the format sent by `writeUTF()` and read by `readUTF()`. You should be sending and reading lines, and they should be terminated with `\r\n`.

Comment: So how do I have to do with print?
something like that?
"GET /index.html HTTP / 1.0 \ r \ n" but with println or with readline?
I'm not sure ... and on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

I did not debug your code, but I think the problem is in the following.

On the server side you should initiate and start a separate thread for every accepted connection. But you are not doing that.

And your server processes all requests in the main thread.

And in this case, until it processes the one iteration (request) of your loop, it won't go to the another iteration, and thus won't process another request.